# $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^t$ is invertible

Tags: matrices

I hate these "easy" proofs. They always slip under my radar.

How do I show that a square matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^t$ is invertible?

Comment: $\det A = \det A^t$.

Comment: If there is a $B$, such that $AB=I$, then $B^tA^t=I$ and by uniqueness of inverse you have $B^t$ as inverse.

Comment: Let $F$ be a field. $A\in F^{n\times n}$ is invertible if and only if $\det A\neq 0$  and $\det A = \det A^{\text{T}}$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If there is a $B$, such that $AB=I$, then $B^tA^t=I$ and by uniqueness of inverse you have $B^t$ as inverse.

Answer (score 3):

You perform Gaussian elimination and it succeeds. This shows that the row rank is equal to the column rank. A square matrix is invertible iff it has maximal rank.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Arash uses $B^tA^t=(AB)^t$ to prove that if a square matrix $A$ is invertible, then $A^t$ is invertible: $(A^{-1})^tA^t=(AA^{-1})^t = I^t=I$, so $A^t$ is invertible by the invertible matrix theorem. This also shows that $(A^t)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^t$.

Here is a proof of the other direction, since the question asks for "if and only if":

Suppose $A^t$ is invertible. Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\left( (A^t)^{-1}\right)^tA\right)^t &= A^t\left(\left( (A^t)^{-1}\right)^t\right)^t \\
&= A^t(A^t)^{-1} \\
&= I
\end{aligned}
$$

(using $(A^t)^t=A$, which we now use again). We have shown

$$\left(\left( (A^t)^{-1}\right)^tA\right)^t=I$$

so

$$\left((A^t)^{-1}\right)^tA = \left(\left(\left( (A^t)^{-1}\right)^tA\right)^t \right)^t = I^t = I$$

so $A$ is invertible.